# Как проверить, что строка состоит из букв латинского алфавита?

Tags: java, android

Должно работать условие при регистрации юзера, что когда он вводит свой `nickName` то он должен состоять из букв латинского алфавита и без пробелов. Как проверить на пробелы я знаю, а как проверить на то, что строка состоит из букв латинского алфавита?

Comment: Вероятно вам нужно проверять не язык, а алфавит. Английский алфавит - всего 26 букв при приведении к одному регистру...

Comment: Уточни, что тебе надо. Одно дело если просто латинские буквы и совсем другое, если надо распознавать граматику.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy мне нужно просто латинские буквы

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов чет мне кажется это не совсем верно... я надеюсь есть более ровный метод. Хотя если не найду, то я уже думал так сделать...

Comment: А чем вас этот не устраивает? Не знаю за жабу, но на питоне if str[i] in englishLetters... - пара строк.

Comment: Можно ведь проверить regexp-ом?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Проверить строку на наличие только латинских символов:

```
boolean onlyLatinAlphabet = string.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
```

Запретить вводить в EditText не латинские символы:

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textFilter"
    android:digits="@string/myAlphaNumeric" />
```

---

```
<string name="myAlphaNumeric">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789</string>
```

Или

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(source);
            if (!matcher.matches()) {
                return "";
            }
           return null;
        }
    }});
```

Comment: А в чем разница между тем как установить в XML файле ограничение для `EditText` или в коде реализовать как вы описали? Только в реализации? или есть разница в работе?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, разница только в реализации